# how to replace special character other than "[" and "]"

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

I am using regex replace function as to replace some special character, but i do not want to replace `[` and `]` also , how can i do this

```
query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 *?:.+\-_]+/g,'');
```

Comment: Note that `+-_` is not just `+`, `-`, and `_` but all characters from `+` (U+002B) to `_` (U+005F).

Answer (score 0):

Try: `query=query.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 *?:.+-_\[\]]+/g,'');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern:

```
/[^ \w*?:.+\][-]+/g
```

Make sure to escape the dash or place it last/first in the character class. Replaced `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`.